# shifting function with dense graph by identity function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, density-function

Let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb R.$ By $id$ I mean the identity function. Define $$(id\cdot f)(x)=id(x)\cdot f(x)=x\cdot f(x)$$ By graph of $f$, we mean $\Gamma(f)=\{\langle x,f(x)\rangle\colon x\in\mathbb{R} \}.$ If the graph of $\Gamma(f)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Then the graph $\Gamma(id\cdot f)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ I think it true and I can see it geometrically since each rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$ will intersect the $\Gamma(f)$ and shifting by $\mathbb{R}$ will not change the density  of $\Gamma(f)$. Is it correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any point $(a,b)$ with $a \neq 0$. Consider $(a,\frac  b a)$. There exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $(x_n,f(x_n)) \to (a, \frac  b a)$. This gives $x_n\to a$  and$f(x_n) \to \frac b a$. Hence $x_n f(x_n) \to b$ and $(x_n, x_nf(x_n)) \to (a,b)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Kavi Rama, you finished , this means $(a,b)$ belongs to the closure of $\Gamma(id\cdot f)$. Since $(a,b)$ is an arbitrary point in $\mathbb R^2$. So, $\Gamma(id\cdot f)$ is dense in $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: @00GB There is just one more point. I took $a \neq 0$. But if all points $(a,b)$ with $a \neq 0$ belong to the closure of the graph the the graph is dense.

Comment: Kavi, Rama, actually we are missing the whole y-axis. Consider any point $(0,b)$ and basic open set in $\mathbb R^2$,say $I\times J$ such that $(0,b)\in I\times J$. Notice that $I\times J$ must contain $(a,b)$ with $a≠0$ .So $\Gamma (id\cdot f)\cap (I\times J)≠∅$ . So, it belongs to closure of $\Gamma(id\cdot f)$. Is there another way to see it.

Comment: @00GB Any point $(0,y)$ on the $y-$ axis can be approximated by $(\frac  1 n , y)$ and then by a point on the graph. This proves that any point in the plane can be approximated by  points on the graph.

Comment: Kavi, I thought about this as well. Thank you very much.